# Работа с OpenDialog - Delphi

Tags: delphi

Передаю файл на FTP таким кодом

```
idFTP1.Put('Test.txt', 'test.txt', false);
```

Как мне вместо файла Test.txt передавать файл который загружен в OpenDialog?

И такой вопрос, если файл который открыт в OpenDialog будет изменятся, будет ли отправляться на FTP измененный файл? Или он будет таким который был загружен изначально?

Comment: `idFTP1.Put(openDialog1.FileName, 'test.txt', false);` Куда загружен? TOpenDialog позволяет выбрать **имя** файла.

Answer (score 1):

`TOpenDialog` не загружает файл, а только лишь выбирает его имя. Имя выбранного файла лежит в `openDialog1.FileName`. Это имя и будет передано **в виде строки**.

```
if openDialog1.Execute then
  idFTP1.Put(openDialog1.FileName, 'test.txt', false);
```

Содержимое файла будет таким каким оно будет на момент доступа к нему.

Answer (score 1):

OpenDialog сам по себе ничего не открывает. Он, как SaveDialog и пр. помогает пользователю выбрать файл. После того, как ты вызовешь диалог открытия файла, то полный путь к файлу, который выбрал пользователь, будет содержать OpenDialog.Filename. Вот пример кода:

```
if(OpenDialog1.Execute) then
Memo1.Lines.Add(OpenDialog1.filename);
```

Вот полная ссылка на то, как работать с OpenDialog:
http://www.delphibasics.ru/TOpenDialog.php